# Friend matching query does not exist

Tags: django

**views.py**

```
def get(self, request):
    form = HomeForm()
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
    users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id, 
                                 friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user), 
                                 friends = friend.users.all())

    args = { 'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'users': users, 'friends': friends}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model): 
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500) 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 

class Friend(models.Model): 
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User) 
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', null=True) 

    @classmethod 
    def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend): 
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create( current_user=current_user ) 
        friend.users.add(new_friend)
```

Comment: Show your models ??

Comment: class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', null=True)

    @classmethod
    def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.add(new_friend)

Comment: Could you edit your post and include the models there?? It would be much appreciated, if you include your code in the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `try except` if Friend matching query doesn't exist.
You have documentation about that : [Try Except](http://pythoncentral.io/catching-python-exceptions-the-try-except-else-keywords/)

In first time you write :

```
try :
    ...

except :
    #when you get doesn't exist
```